# .htaccess redirect non-www to www but leave sub-domains

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I want to achieve the following:

> http:// domain.com -> http://www.domain.com
>
> http://sub.domain.com -> http:// sub.domain.com(and not http:// www.sub.domain.com)

I have been searching a lot today but can't find a solution. Hope someone helps here.

Comment: Just got an answer from another thread. Hope it helps some people here.

>RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

>RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.

>RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already got a solution and even tried this. It works! :)